# How can I install an outlet in a disused hot tub breaker panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, receptacle, outdoor, hot-tub

I removed the old hot tub in my backyard and I would like to know how to reuse the existing electrical setup to put an outlet there instead.

The first picture shows the electrical panel that was connected to the hot tub. Unfortunately I didn't have the chance to take a picture of the wiring before they disconnected the hot tub.  The cable going to the hot tub has 6 wires: 2 red, 2 black, 1 green, 1 white.  I'd like to put an outlet on the other end to connect string lighting and a electric portable grill.

Could someone please show me the correct way of rewiring this? 220V is preferable and I  suppose it is capable of handling this load.

[image: Hot Tub Panel]

The second picture shows the electrical panel connected to my AC units.  It is daisy chained to the first panel.  The cable going to the hot tub panel has 4 wires: blue, red, green, white.

[image: AC Panel]
[image: Wires from the wall]

Comment: [Related questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adiy.stackexchange.com+hot+tub+panel+outlet&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS1019US1019)

Comment: With the two separate 2-pole GFCI breakers you have (one 30 A and one 20 A) you will be able to have one 240 V receptacle AND one duplex 120 V receptacle. The duplex 120 V receptacle could be in what is called a multiwire branch circuit so in effect you would have TWO 120 V receptacles each rated for 20 A. Nice. Where do you want to locate these receptacles? On the wall of the house or at the location where the hot tub was located?

Comment: Something is missing or not labeled right. Is there a feed breaker in the main panel? If so, what size is it? I see white "into the wall" - are there other wires also going "into the wall"? Also, the AC box looks like it has neutral and ground on the same bar.

Comment: .The disadvantage of wiring the duplex 120 V receptacle as a multiwire branch circuit would be that the two receptacles of the duplex would not be independent as far as a breaker trip--if one receptacle would trip, then it would trip the other one. To get greater independence you would have to changeout the 20 A 2-pole GFCI breaker for a pair of 1-pole 20 A GFCI breakers. This would be an additional expense and might never or rarely come into play if you would not get trips.

Comment: @JimStewart The main hot tub circuit may not have had neutral. But neutral is in that box already on the neutral bar.

Comment: Looks like four insulated wires are going into the conduit for the hot tub--white, red, blue and green. One hopes there would be enough extra of the white in the box at the location of the hot tube to make connections.

Comment: @JimStewart the hot tub was only 5ft away from its panel and was also 18 inches away from the side of the house.  I would put the outlet on the wall. This section of the wall is also covered and doesn't get wet when it rains.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact sorry the angle of the picture makes hard to see, but there are 4 cables coming from the wall, white, black, red, and gray (it has no sleeve). I am attaching a 3rd picture to zoom in it.  I was also confused seeing the green and white wires connected to the same bar (in the second picture)

Comment: Do you know what is the power or current requirement for the portable electric grill you have in mind? Do you know whether this grill has a need for a neutral or is it just 240 V? For safety reasons grills should not he operated right under the soffit of a house and a power cord from the wall to the location of grill is not optimal. You might want the 240 V receptacle on a pedestal at the location of the grill. The 120 V receptacle for the lighting string could be on the wall. But maybe in the real world grills are often operated under roofs to get in the shade or out of the rain.

Comment: For future reference, individual wires (like the white, black, red, gray) are referred to as wires. Cables refer to groups of wires that are inside an outer sheath. That gray wire is ground, which is fine. Green (or bare) ground and white on the same bar used to be normal but now is only allowed in the main panel (these are both subpanels).

Comment: @JimStewart Something like this https://www.amazon.com/Hamilton-Beach-25360-Removable-Extra-Large/dp/B00F0RBF3E. Nothing fancy. I would put it way when done using it.  I didn't know about the safety code, but I see many homes having an outdoor kitchen right next to their patio door and they added a "cover" (can't call it a roof)

Comment: A lot of electric outdoor grills seem to be only 1800 W or less and probably for 120 V. The would mean they would draw 15 A at 120 V and so the labelling would say plug into a 20 A circuit. If this is all you want then a single duplex 120 V receptacle would do. Just be sure you understand the specifications of the grill before you buy it and then put in a receptacle that will provide what it needs. The nice thing is that you already have GFCI breakers so the outside receptacles do not have to be GFCI.

Comment: I agree that the location on the wall is best. A pedestal in the yard in a tripping hazard for people and an impact hazard for a dog running around the yard.

Comment: But suppose you wanted to run TWO 1800 W grills at the same time or a pizza oven and a separate grill? Then a single duplex receptacle would do this IF it is wired as a mltiwire branch circuit. This should be no more expensive and would simply mean that both hots would be used and the neutral. Do you intend to DIY or have an electrician do this?

Comment: Not trying to discourage your use of the disused hot tub circuits but that grill you are looking at is only 1200 W (surely 120 V) so 10 A. You could run an extension cord from an outdoor receptacle 50 ft away and power that. Of course make sure that any receptacle would be GFCI so that a pet dog who decided to chew the cord would be protected.

Comment: @JimStewart now that the hot tub is gone, I am converting the space to a sitting area.  The main purpose of the outlet is for the string lights.  Would be nice if I can also plug the grill there, but I do have options as you pointed out w/ a long extension cable to an existing outlet.  I can do the work myself if it is a matter of reconnecting the wires correctly to panel and put an outlet on the other side.  The cable is inside a tube that runs along the wall, so it is already protected. What I need help with is the wiring part. Thanks

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact would you confirm that the OP has the right details on how to wire this circuit?

Answer (score 1):

How far from the location of the breaker box do you want to locate the new receptacle? Wires from the breaker box to the receptacle box must be in conduit.

You may be able to cut off the existing (fairly large) conduit the wires to the hot tub were in and terminate the cut end in a box fastened to the wall below the breaker box. But if you want the receptacle displaced laterally it might be better to use new conduit from the side. An expert will have to tell you the details of how to do that. Possibly the receptacle box could be fastened to the side or bottom of the breaker box so you would not have to make new holes in the stucco.

Hopefully one of the experts here will tell you the proper electrical practice and the probable code requirements for doing what you want to do.

Where is this property located? The local electrical code will specify how to do this.

If all you want is a duplex 120 V receptacle, and you want to utilize the existing 20 A 2-pole breaker you have in place, then you would connect two wires to the 20 A 2-pole breaker and connect these to the hot side of the duplex receptacle (one wire to each of the two receptacles of the duplex receptacle) AND break off the connecting jumper tab  on the hot side.

The white neutral would be connected to the neutral side and the jumper tab left in place. Then connect the green ground to the ground connection of the receptacle. This would give you a multiwire branch circuit providing two separate 20 A receptacles. You could put in a standard 20 A duplex receptacle and this would allow using appliances or equipment which had a 20 A plug should you ever need that. These also accept a standard 15 A plug.

[Video](https://youtu.be/rapPtMscrI0?si=JpAFM-KSx7lY1EJj) showing how to remove the jumper tab on the hot side only for a multiwire branch circuit.

[Video](https://youtu.be/c9ComAMAneY?si=xVh-VInJ0MAgFxYR) whether you are required to use a 20 A duplex receptacle. I interpret this to mean that you are not required to use a 20 A receptacle but I think you should do so. A 20 A receptacle costs a little more but it would allow plugging in a 20 A plug which might come in handy some day. You might want to plug in something which has a 20 A plug or some workman might want to plug in some near 20 A equipment with a 20 A plug to do some work on your house.

EDIT

The use of a multiwire branch circuit would make available up to 20 A in each hot wire and these would flow through a common neutral. However this does NOT mean the neutral would be carrying 40 A. The two hot wires are on different "legs" and so are 180 deg out of phase and so cancel each other. The neutral wire carried a current equal to the difference in the currents in the two hot legs.

For example suppose you had a 1600 W grill plugged into one of the receptacles and an 1800 W pizza oven in the other. Your 20 A GFCI breaker would handle this just fine. The grill would draw 13.3 A and the pizza oven 15 A. The current in the neutral would be only 15 A - 13.3 A = 1.7 A. A multiwire branch circuit is a nifty arrangement!

Comment: In the first picture, you can see 2 conduits on the bottom of the panel.  The right one goes straight down to the ground and runs along the bottom of the wall for about 8ft.  Putting the outlet at this location of the wall would be ideal.  I would need to extend the wires or fish a new cable in the conduit else the outlet would be to close to the ground.

Comment: If I understand your instructions, This is how I need to reconnect the wires from the hot tub cable into the panel: white wire goes into the right bar where 3 white wires are already connected to, leave the green as currently connected, 2 black wires into the right side breaker (there are 4 screws at the bottom, 1st is used by a white wire, I can insert the black wire into the 2nd and 3rd screws or 2nd and 4th).  I am clear on wiring the outlet, I believe it's the same as those indoor outlets and switches which I have done few times.  Thanks

Comment: That seems correct. To use the existing 20 A 2-pole breaker you must use both black wires and you must connect one black wire to one of the receptacles of the duplex and the other black wire to the other receptacle of the duplex. AND you must break away the little jumper tab connecting the two receptacles. If you fail to break off this tab and you turn on the power you would have a full 240 V short circuit which would trip a breaker and might cause damage.

Comment: Don't forget to remove the tab https://youtu.be/rapPtMscrI0?si=JpAFM-KSx7lY1EJj

Comment: Is this 20 A 2-pole GFCI breaker a common trip? Does it have one one neutral to serve both poles or does it have separate neutrals, one for each pole?

Comment: If there is only one neutral wire going into the recpetacle you DO NOT break the jumper on the neutral side. But if you would mistakenly do so you can use a wire as a jumper. you would not have to buy another receptacle, but try not to do this.

Comment: NOTE  The white neutral wire from the receptacle to the 20 A breaker box DOES NOT go to the neutral bar. It connects to a place on the breaker itself. Before you start wiring this  get straight how GFCI breakers are to be connected.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jim.  Great list of links.  What are the benefits for using both black wires as opposed to just 1 wire as jay613 explained below?

Comment: Your 20 A 2-pole GFCI breaker MIGHT require you to use both hot wires. I don't know . . . maybe you could use only one hot wire and the neutral. The benefit of using both hot wires is that you would be able to draw 20 A from each receptacle for 40 A total. So if you wanted to you could power two appliances at the same time  even if each one was drawing over 10 A for over 20 A total. If you use only one hot wire, you would be limited to 20 A total from both receptacles. This is made possible by your having a 2-pole breaker rated at 20 A in each hot wire.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a 50 amp feed to the hot tub, and now-unused 30A and 20A 2-pole GFCI breakers there.   The 20A one is suitable for outlets.

If all you want is a normal 120V outlet at that location, remove the tail feeding the hot tub, replace it with a 1/2" watertight PVC connector and a very short piece of 1/2" PVC conduit, and at the other end install an outdoor outlet box and an outdoor-rated non-GFCI outlet.   Connect it through the conduit, hot to one side of the 20A GFCI breaker, neutral goes to the breaker's neutral terminal and ground goes to the ground bus.  The breaker's neutral pigtail is already connected to the neutral bus and should remain so.

The other side of the 20A breaker will go unused.    If you ever use it for anything, just know that any fault on either circuit will trip both circuits.  At that time you can decide if to rearrange things or buy single-pole breakers. You don't need to do that now.

Just for clarity, you can't install an outlet "in" the hot tub's breaker box, but I hope right next to it is just as good.

Comment: Thanks @jay613.  This method is straight forward and sounds like what is shown in this video https://www.popularmechanics.com/home/how-to-plans/how-to/a20318/how-to-install-an-electrical-outlet-from-a-sub-panel/ . Although his breaker has only 1 screw at the bottom while mine has 2 with a white wire already connected to it.

Comment: The 2-pole GFCi breaker that I have seen has a place for THREE wires to connect. The outer two are for the hot wires and the center one (labelled "N") is for the neutral wire to the receptacle. This breaker also has a white pigtail coming from it. This pigtail is to be connected to the neutral bar. This is different from the connection of a basic 2-pole breaker which only has connections for the two hot wires. The neutral from the receptacle in that case (non-GFCI breaker) is connected to the neutral bar.

Comment: My answer was wrong regarding the neutral wires and I corrected it now.  Your breaker has THREE terminals.  Two are for live conductors and you can use either of them.   One is for your circuit's neutral conductor, and you must connect your circuit's white wire there, not to the neutral bus as the guy in your video does.  His breaker is not GFCI.  And your breaker has it's neutral pigtail already connected to the neutral bus, you must leave that.    There are lots of other details to get right.  Wouldn't hurt to get an electrician to guide you the first time you do something like this.

Comment: I edited my answer to explain the benefit of using both black wires.

Comment: Thank you both @JimStewart and jay613.  This has been a very educational thread.  I think it's now clear and I understand the various concepts behind it which is a big bonus for future use.  After all, wiring this outlet is really simple. Leave everything as is and connect 1 or 2 black wires to the 20A duplex pole.  On the other end of the cable, the white wire goes to the neutral (silver) terminal of the outlet, the black wires go to the load (brass) terminals and the green wire goes to the ground (green) terminal.  Break the little bridge between the 2 brass terminals to have 2 circuits.

Comment: Just to be clear you only break the little bridge on the hot side if you are using the two hots from the 2-pole GFCI breaker.  If you are using only one hot from the breaker you should leave the bridge intact.